# NSError** issue back propagate in multi function call

Tags: ios, objective-c, error-handling, nserror

Facing an issue in back propagation of error in multi functional call.

For example,

```
NSError *error = nil;
EMSPlanFolder *planner = [[EMSPlanFolder sharedPlanBuilder] buildPlanFromParsePlan:plan withError:&error];
if (error) {
   //error
}
```

Next, it goes to function:

```
- (EMSPlanFolder*)buildPlanFromParsePlan:(EMParsedPlan*)parsedPlan withError:(NSError *__autoreleasing*)err
{
 ....
 ....
 [self deserializePlan:parsedPlan forPlan:newPlanFolder allowingNoEndDate:NO withError:err];
  if(err && *err) {
   [newPlanFolder.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
 [EMSPlanFolder deletePlan:newPlanFolder];
    }];
  return nil;
  }
 return newPlanFolder;
}
```

Next, it goes to:

```
   - (void)deserializePlan:(NSArray*)planElements forPlan:(LMSPlanFolder*)planFolder allowingNoEndDate:(BOOL)allowNoEndDate withError:(NSError *__autoreleasing*)err {
     ....
     ....
     if(err) {
      *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Application" code:-1 userInfo:@{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plan was not found."]}];
     }
     return;
    }
```

Problem is, it leads to crash when it back propagates to first code snippet. Any suggestions on it

Comment: Can you show the crash description and its stack trace?

Comment: Can you please add crash detail which you are getting on above function ?\

Comment: Sorry no crash description is logged, I just get a msg stating "exc_bad_access code=exc_i386_gpflt"

Comment: *** -[NSError retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x6000056545e0

Comment: Does the error generation in your third snippet take place in a code block, e. g. within `performBlockAndWait:` of `NSManagedObjectContext`?

Comment: Is there something async to calculate if there is an error somewhere in the middle of your eluded code?

Comment: @macmoonshine: Yes it does in `performBlockAndWait:`

Answer (score 1):

Apple frameworks often execute blocks in nested autorelease pools. Your error reference is autoreleasing, and thus the error is released when the block has finished executing. To avoid this use a strong local `__block` variable to keep the error. Try something like that:

```
__block NSError *theError = nil;

[context performBlockAndWait:^{
     //
    [self deserializePlan:parsedPlan 
                  forPlan:newPlanFolder 
        allowingNoEndDate:NO 
                withError:&theError]; // <- store the error ARP safe
}];
*err = theError;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
NSError *error = nil;
EMSPlanFolder *planner = [[EMSPlanFolder sharedPlanBuilder] buildPlanFromParsePlan:plan withError:&error];
if (error) {
   //error
}

- (EMSPlanFolder*)buildPlanFromParsePlan:(EMParsedPlan*)parsedPlan withError:(NSError **)err
{
 ....
 ....
 [self deserializePlan:parsedPlan forPlan:newPlanFolder allowingNoEndDate:NO withError:&err];
  if(err == nil) {
   [newPlanFolder.managedObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{
 [EMSPlanFolder deletePlan:newPlanFolder];
    }];
  return nil;
  }
 return newPlanFolder;
}

- (void)deserializePlan:(NSArray*)planElements forPlan:(LMSPlanFolder*)planFolder allowingNoEndDate:(BOOL)allowNoEndDate withError:(NSError **)err {
     ....
     ....
     if(err) {
      *err = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"Application" code:-1 userInfo:@{ NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plan was not found."]}];
     }
     return;
}
```